# Strange new iOS 7 errors: receiver from DB / ForceShrinkPersistentStore_NoLock

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios7

Good day.

I have a project that uses a lot of network connections with SSL. This project runs fine and without errors on iOS 5 and 6. But with new iOS 7 i keep getting these two errors:

```
ERROR: unable to get the receiver data from the DB

ForceShrinkPersistentStore_NoLock -delete- We do not have a BLOB or TEXT column type.  Instead, we have 5.
```

They are not connected in any way and i did keep getting first one for few weeks, then later i got this second one too.

They are received on my application start, at that point i send few HTTP POST's and process received data. I cannot catch where do these errors come from.

I could find them if i could understand them. Anyone know what do they mean or on what cases one can cause them?

Comment: I should add that these errors do not raise any exception and do not disturb app functionality in any way.

Comment: Is your app using CoreData? They changed some options they use with sqlite storage in iOS 7 that sound like they could be related (I'll find a link to the WWDC video it is mentioned in if you confirm you're using CD)

Comment: No i am not CD, but i would like that link, thanks!

Comment: It's session 207, https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/

Comment: It appears that this error is received on all devices that had application installed BEFORE ios7 and then survived the update. Now, no matter how many times i rebuild i get those errors. Deletion of the app and restart of device helped i think.

Comment: Getting this with regular ol' Cocoa...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I also had the first of your problems just today:

```
ERROR: unable to get the receiver data from the DB
```

I don't know the reason (maybe somehow the cache got corrupt) but
deleting all of the simulator's Applications folder made the problem go away for me.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0-64/Applications/*
```

Comment: Well on Monday morning, both errors were gone (no one touched the code at all). So these "ghost errors" are still a mystery. iOS 7 still throws "BLOB TEXT" error but not that often. Device and simulators iOS 5 + 6 stay quiet. I accept this answer because there is no problem anymore, even though it resolved itself. Thank you for your support.

Comment: This is perhaps obvious but if you are also debugging on an actual iPhone delete the app and rerun it.

Comment: Note that the command above won't work unless you escape the space character in the path (`Application\ Support`)

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem, but is is while debugging on a iOS device (iPhone 4 iOS 7.0.4)

Not sure what causes this... But I tried deleting the app on device and rerunning, then the error is gone.

Answer (score 3):

This error generally occurs in iOS7 and reason might be **cache issues**.
I fixed the problem by **deleting folder of simulator**.

Steps :

Right click on **“Finder”** window select **“Go to Folder”**

Paste **“~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/”**

This will open iPhone Simulator folder containing simulators used in execution.

Now, **delete 7.x folder.**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Got same problem today. In my case `ERROR: unable to get the receiver data from the DB` error message was not resolved by cleaning app from simulator/device. Once running app for a while error got reported again. Also it was logged each time I did `[NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:...]` calls.

Found it was related to caching responses. Setting policy to ignore local cache eliminated error logging:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration  defaultSessionConfiguration];
defaultConfigObject.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject
                                                          delegate: nil
                                                     delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:completion];
[dataTask resume];
```

Note: Session has to be invalidated once not needed any more, otherwise will cause memory leak

Answer (score 1):

I too faced a similar problem..

Including the above suggestion I also ignored the cache in my post request

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

and the problem never appeared for me...

Comment: I have a number of JSON posts to my webservice. The problem only occurs on one that gets > 40K of data back. Changing the cachePolicy to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData caused the problem to go away.

Answer (score 1):

It was easier to fix for me:

Just Deleted the app from the simulator (like you would from you phone - no need for me to delete some folders) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting derived data solved this for me.

Window > Organiser > Projects

Select your project, hit delete beside derived data.